# through-wall meaning

Tags: meaning, understanding

I was reading a standard (DS-1 Drill Stem Inspection) and I saw the following sentence:

> The reference standard for flux leakage transverse flaw detection
> units shall be a **through-wall** drilled hole standard prepared from a
> length of pipe of the same nominal diameter as the pipe to be
> inspected.The hole size shall be 1/16 inch, ±1/64 inch indiameter.

I couldn't completely understand the word "through-wall hole".
what has me confused is this:
does The hole have to go completely through the body of the pipe(as in you can see through it) or does it mean that "put your drill bit perpendicular to body of the pipe and make an arbitrary hole depth with the specified diameter"?

Comment: I see nothing in those words to suggest perpendicular or partial depth. I would understand "through-wall hole" to mean all the way through the wall. Caveat: I know nothing about the technical topic of that standard.

Comment: @AdrianHHH We were checking some pipes against this standard and saw a manufacturer making  partial holes (they are one of the big ones), while others are  making complete(through) holes in their pipes. It got me thinking which one is the correct one.

Comment: Perhaps you should find a Q&A website or forum related to that sort of pipes and their quality standards.